# Python label using stringvar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to append a text string to a label in Tkinter.

I am getting "label_text" is not defined. I have assigned label-text to a StringVar but still, I am getting "name label-text is not defined"

I appreciate any help to get rid of the error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import *
import time

def test():
    delay = 3.0
    time.sleep(delay)
    print_to_gui('Files currently transferring')
    time.sleep(delay)
    print_to_gui('Currently merging all pdfs')

# Append `text_string` to `label_text`, which is displayed in `out_label`
def print_to_gui(text_string):
    label_text.set(label_text.get() + '\n' + text_string)
    # Force the GUI to update
    Root.update()

def clear_label():
    label_text.set('')
    Root.update()

def main():
    Root = Tk()
    label_text = StringVar()
    Root.wm_title("testest")
    Root.minsize(width=300, height=150)
    Root.maxsize(width=300, height=150)
    b = Button(Root, text='Run test', command = test)
    b.config(width=15, height=1)
    b.pack()
    # A Label to display output from the `test` function
    out_label = Label(Root, textvariable=label_text, wraplength=250, bg='red')
    label_text.set('Click button to start')
    out_label.pack()
    Root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Comment: Just as a note, using ``.update()`` is not the wisest choice.

Comment: Use ```.after()``` instead.

Comment: I looked into the Tutorial - 9.2. Still don't know how to make the StringVar global

Comment: Use the keyword ```global```